# Problems logging in to English Language & Usage

Tags: bug

I joined EL&U a day or so ago, and at first had no problems, then suddenly earlier today, the site refused to recognise me.  This seemed to be a feature of accessing the site via the Chrome browser, which insisted I log on via google, and I finally got round the problem by switching to the Edge browser.

One odd thing was that this *suddenly* began happening, for no apparent reason.

Has anyone else encountered this glitch/bug/problem/feature?

Comment: I have been using google chrome which asks me to log in once using my google account. After that the browser keeps me logged in (even if I close individual tabs / windows) as long as I don't specifically log out -- so if you are having login issues you might try to login using chrome and remain logged in, so as to **avoid repeated logging in** and attendant issues.

Comment: I initially signed up with the email/password option (which is where I am now) but Chrome currently insists I enter via my google account.  If I do, I'm a blank slate.  :-( .  This is obviously not a problem if you **initially** register via google, but I didn't, partly because I never check my gmail account, and wanted to use my normal email address.  Currently, the log-on-via-Edge fudge seems to be working, so I suppose I'll have to live with that.

Comment: Does it happen if you're in an incognito window in Chrome? Does it happen if you disable all your Chrome add-ons?

Comment: @RobinHamilton If any one login method works, then it's fine -- see if you can remain logged in, if your browser allows that -- I appreciate your recent comments on certain questions;  both your interest and your expertise are most welcome at this English language & usage website!

Comment: Many thanks everyone -- this clears it up a bit.  I might try the "incognito window" option.  The only reason I use Chrome at all is because a [free -- and exceedingly useful] program which I use constantly -- Zotero -- doesn't [yet] work with Edge.  I had a singularly unpleasant few hours when I was (essentially) cut off from your society!  And thanks to @English Student for the kind remarks.

Comment: @RobinHamilton you are most welcome; and I hope you will be a regular and active member here!

Comment: Logging on via a Chrome incognito window worked!  Whoopie!  (Thanks, @ Mr. Shiny and New.)

Comment: @RobinHamilton Do take note that Incognito will not keep you signed in, and you'll see a fresh sign in screen when you restart the browser.

Comment: Having used the "Incognito" option for a little bit, it's a total pain, actually worse than having to run two separate browsers.  So I think I'll go back to Edge for EL&U, and Chrome (mostly for the sake of access to Zotero) for Everything Else.  Between the Devil and a hard place, as they say ...

Comment: You might try FireFox, which is also free and has a lot of the nice things about Chrome but doesn't strong-arm you into using your Google account for everything...

Comment: Hey, that's an idea!  Zotero works with it, so it trumps Edge that way. Going to try that now. Why I use Zotero, incidentally -- it's a Web-page-saver + bibliography program, so for me it kills two birds with one stone.  I dump virtually everything into it.  Neat!  [And no, they don't pay me to say things like that.  :-)  ]